# Adding a tenant ID header to MessagingGateway for every message sent

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an `abstract class` in a library project where I do:

```java
this.eventGateway.publishEvent("SomeEvent", null);
```

and `EventGateway` is this:

```java
@MessagingGateway
public interface EventGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "SomeChannel")
    void publishEvent(@Header(value = "EventName") String event, @Payload Object payload);
}
```

and my `SomeChannel` definition:

```java
@Bean(name = "SomeChannel)
public MessageChannel someChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
}
```

Now it's been working fine until we wanted to use the library in a multi-tenant environment, where we want to add a header (say, `"TenantId"`) to every message we send using `EventGateway`. The obvious solution would be adding `EventGateway` this method:

```java
@Gateway(requestChannel = "SomeChannel")
    void publishTenantEvent(@Header(value = "EventName") String event, @Header(value = "TenantId") String tenantId, @Payload Object payload);
```

and using it like:

```java
final TenantContext context = TenantContextHolder.getContext();
final Tenant tenant = context.getTenant();
this.eventGateway.publishEvent("SomeEvent", tenant.getId(), null);
```

But changing every place where we do `this.eventGateway.publishEvent("SomeEvent", null);` to above is almost equal to writing the library from scratch.

FWIW, my `SomeChannel` definition is as follows:

Is there a way that I can add `"TenantId"` header to every message I send if it's present in `TenantContextHolder` (a class holding a thread local variable `TenantContext`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Gateway` has a:

```
/**
 * Specify additional headers that will be added to the request message.
 * @return the headers.
 */
GatewayHeader[] headers() default { };
```

That `@GatewayHeader` has this:

```
/**
 * @return The {@code Expression} to be evaluated to produce a value for the header.
 */
String expression() default "";
```

which you can declare for your use-case like:

```
@Gateway(requestChannel = "SomeChannel", 
         headers = @GatewayHeader(name = "TenantId", 
                                  expression = "T(TenantContextHolder).context.tenant.id"))
```

Where you have to use a fully-qualified class name for that `TenantContextHolder`.
See more info about `T` operator in SpEL docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types. The getters are resolved from the property names.

Comment: Thanks. We have a use chase where a `Tenant` might not be present in thread local. To support null `Tenant`, could you guide me on how do I create a method and call it in `expression` of `@GatewayHeader`?

Comment: For that purpose you have to use a *Safe Navigation Operator*: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation. `T(TenantContextHolder).context?.tenant?.id`